# Security and data access to a WebAPI with OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, maui

I'm developing a system that includes a mobile (.NET MAUI) and web app (ASP.NET MVC) that connects to a Web API that manages all the bussiness logic and data. The point is that this is my first-time using OAuth for authentication and authorization. I'm not clear what is the right way to restrict access based on the user access level. Where should access levels be established? In the API? In the Identity server? How is the right way to implement it?

[image: System arquitectura]

An example could be that a user that manages a specific store can only access the inventory of that specific store, or in the basest case, when the request of the stores are made only returns the one that are on his control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Authorize attribute at the controller action level to achieve this. Further you can define the roles (can define user roles at identity server level) for the users who will have access to that method.

For more info :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Hope this helps.